# Warning: `auto` in formal parameter

Tags: c++, function, g++, compiler-warnings, auto

I executed the following program -

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void display(const vector<auto> &arr) {
    for (auto const &val: arr) 
        cout<<val<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a (6);
    display(a);

    vector<double> b (3);
    display(b);
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives the following warning (without any error) -

```
warning: use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration only available with ‘-fconcepts’
5 | void display(const vector<auto> &arr) {                                                                                                                          
  |                           ^~~~
```

**Why am I getting this warning & what is this warning about ?**

**Should I be using `auto` in as formal parameter here ??**

**What can be the alternative way if it's the wrong approach ??**

Comment: have you tried using `-fconcepts`

Comment: Well, I do not know about it @M.M !!

Comment: @RishiK. See [Constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau for the resource !!

Comment: Why not use templates? Either for the contained type or for the container itself. Or better yet, take note of how the standard library itself handle these things: Not by passing containers but by passing a range using iterators.

Comment: Yeah, I got it ! The actual problem was that, I haven't studied about templates yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want a template:

```
template<typename T>
void display(const vector<T>& arr)
{
    for (auto const &val: arr) 
        cout<<val<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```